# How to declare a member variable that contains a reference to outer class?

Tags: c++

I have the code as below:

```
class outer {
public:
  class inner {
    outer & o;
  public:
    inner(outer & o): o(o) {}
  };

  inner i(*this);
};
```

But this gives me error saying:

```
error: expect specifier before token '*'
```

How can I do this? Do I have to use pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Initialize `i` in `outer`'s constructor's initializer list.

```
inner i;

outer(): i(*this) {}
```

2) (C++11 only) Use a brace-initializer for `i`. In this case you *have* to use braces, not parentheses.

```
inner i{*this};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. You can do it in the constructor of the outer class

```
outer() : i(*this) {}
```

This is way is error prone though, since instance is not constructed yet and `this` is incomplete. Generally **don't use** `this` **in initializer lists** (gcc will give you a warning)

The other way is only valid in C++ 11

```
inner i { *this };
```

Comment: There's no substantial difference between the two methods. Non-static members are initialized in declaration order. If there's a ctor-initializer then it's used, otherwise if there's a brace-initializer it's used, otherwise it's default-initialized and it goes onto the next member.

Comment: Anyway, `*this` is an lvalue, and there's only a problem if there's an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. In this case there won't be, since the parameter is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The member `i` can be declared in the class but it can't be initialized if you are using a compiler that supports C++98 only. You can initialize it in the implementation of the constructor of `outer`.

```
class outer {
public:
  class inner {
    outer & o;
  public:
    inner(outer & o): o(o) {}
  };

  outer() : i(*this) {}
  inner i;
};
```